# why can't create a .Net project with Eclipse?

Tags: c#, .net, eclipse

I want to create a .NET Core project in Eclipse IDE, but Eclipse does not find an available project template. So I can't create the project.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

I installed the aCute. I specified dotnet.exe in Preferences.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no project template for .Net. Just create a general project (_File > New > Project...: General > Project_) and drop your *.cs files into the project. See also the screenshot here: https://github.com/eclipse/aCute

Comment: Thanks. And how can I create a project or solution file to run the project?